# Can't instantiate the MongoClient class

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb, nashorn

I'm trying to use the MongoDB driver with Nashorn but I can't instantiate the MongoClient class, do you have any ideas why?

```
var mongodb = Packages.com.mongodb;
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var mongoClient = new MongoClient();
```

-- Running the test:

```
jjs -cp mongo-java-driver-2-9-3.jar mongo.js
```

-- result:

```
mongo.js:4 TypeError: [JavaPackage com.mongodb.MongoClient] is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mongo documentation is out of sync with the Java repo (moved to GitHub).  Prior to 2.10, the name was Mongo, not MongoClient.  You need to use the 2.10.x jar from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads or http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.10.0/.

```
var mongodb = Packages.com.mongodb;
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var mongo = new MongoClient("localhost");

print(mongo);
```

Then:

```
/Volumes/Elephant/Users/jlaskey/jjstest% jjs -cp mongo-2.10.1.jar mongodb.js
Mongo: localhost/127.0.0.1:27017
```

Comment: The download links have a very strange ordering - it confused me as well at first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , look for the driver in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads .

mongo-java-driver-2.9.3.jar will not work.